# Видоизменение имен функциий

Tags: c++, компилятор

Для чего компиляторы C++ "манглят" имена функций.

Comment: что бы линкер потом мог отличить одноименные функции с разными параметрами. линкер же про параметры уже ничего не знает

Comment: "Манглят" ? Не понимаю, что это такое :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman mangle

Comment: ааа :)) спасибо! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите, компиляторы C++ унаследовали линкер из C.

В C-шном линкере имя функции напрямую отображалось на имя объекта. Это работало, поскольку в C нет перегруженных функций.

Но в C++ перегрузки функций есть (а также пространства имён и классы), и функции

```
int f(int x) { ... }
```

и

```
int f(int x, int y) { ... }
```

получили бы одинаковое имя! А компоновщик такую ситуацию обрабатывать не умел, для него все имена должны были быть уникальны. Для того, чтобы написанные выше две функции смогли скомпоноваться, и чтобы и не менять логику компоновщика, придумали простой выход: кодировать сигнатуру функции, то есть, типы параметров (а также имя класса и пространство имён), в имени, передавать компоновщику дополненное имя.

---

В принципе, такое видоизменение имён не является обязательным, и не требуется стандартом. Тем не менее, это популярная техника реализации взаимодействия компилятора и компоновщика, которая применяется как в стандарте POSIX, так и в Windows ABI.

Comment: получается нельзя запретить искажать имена перегруженных функций?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov: Не, нельзя, при этом не слинкуется.